# EF4 DBContext and MVC3. The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, I am learning to make a very simple MVC + EF page. It is supposed to get a list of countries into a dropDownList. And I run into this error:

**ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

I thought I was aware of that DBContext will be disposed, so I pull up the values in string and array string[]. Why do I still get this issue?

**View.cshtml...**

```
<select id="register-country">
    @foreach (var country in ViewBag.Countries) { //******** ERROR HERE ********
        <option value="@country[0]">@country[1]</option> 
    }
</select>
```

**Controller.cs ...**

```
public virtual ActionResult RegisterDialogPartial() {
    var csm = new CountryStateModelRepository();
    ViewBag.Countries = csm.GetCountries();
    return PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._RegisterDialogPartial);
}
```

**DataAccessLayer ...**

```
public class CountryStateModelRepository {
    public IQueryable<string[]> GetCountries() {
        using (var db = new CountryStateModelContainer()) {
            return db.Country.Select(r => new string[] { r.CountryISO3, r.CountryName });
        }
    }
    public IQueryable<string> GetCountryStates(string countryISO3) {
        using (var db = new CountryStateModelContainer()) {
            return db.CountryState.Filter(r => r.CountryISO3 == countryISO3.ToUpper()).Select(r=>r.CountryISO3).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Say hello to deferred execution. You cannot dispose context if you return `IQueryable`. You must execute the query prior to disposing the context by calling for example `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that Entity Framework and LINQ work such that the query is not executed until the values are enumerated (and in this case, that doesn't happen until your view). If you wish to enumerate the values at the time of your function call modify your method as such:

```
return db.Country.Select(r => new string[] { r.CountryISO3, r.CountryName }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: So, I tried to add .AsEnumerable() and .AsQueryable() and .ToList(). Also, turned the lazy loading thing off in the edmx properties. They still all return the same error. Doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I can't say exactly what's wrong without building the project myself, but if you are still getting the errors I'd try two things. One, try removing the 'using' and explicitly creating a datacontext object and explicitly assigning its value to a local variable, then return it; or, could simply be you need to clean/rebuild the project.

When you do AsEnumerable are you also setting the return type of the function call to IEnumerable?

Comment: 1. Yes, I set the return type to each of the correct coresponding ones.   2. The main code is pretty much here, except there is a bit more code as you can see it returns a partial view, it goes back into a JQuery dialog when there is an ajax call. That is, this partial view is called later individually after the full page has finished rendering, but I supposed that has nothing to do with EF? no more code functions other than those.

Comment: Tom, did you try the debugging step of removing the using statement and explicitly assigning variables? What I'd do is create my datacontext object; assign the query variable to a local variable in the function, and put a breakpoint at that point in the code, see what the results of the query are, and see if that breakpoint is hit before the exception is thrown.

Comment: Got it! :D turns out array new string[] was not good, an error says something about array cannot be init in such call...blah', anonymous type new {r.ISO3, r.Name} also no good. Then I just return select(r=>r) no more fancy stuff. magic! it works!